# How to identify "throw exceptions" in a Java program regarding Integer.parseInt method

Tags: exception

I am new to Java and I am having trouble understanding a question. I am asked to select which of the following choices throws an exception. The options are:

```
1.) Integer.parseInt(" ")
2.) Integer.parseInt("54 ")
3.) Integer.parseInt("")
4.) Integer.parseInt("-54")
5.) Integer.parseInt("54n")
```

To answer this question, I need some explanations. What does the Integer.parseInt method do? Doesn't it turn an integer into a String? What sort of arguments are illegal to put inside this method. For example, are you allowed to include negative numbers? Strings? Or does it only accept integers?

I was also wondering if you could clarify what "throws an exception" means. I have a rough idea, I think it just means that if there is an error in your program, it gets terminated. Howevere, you can use the "try-catch-finally" method to try and predicate any errors your program would have and write a possible code to fix it?

Sorry for all the questions, I just want to understand this completely.

Comment: "Doesn't it turn an integer into a String?"  No, it does the opposite: turn a String into an Integer.

Comment: Use official java docs to work out what specific functions do. Here is the javadoc for [Integer.parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)). Google is your friend. It would have been faster for you to google [exception throwing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html) then to ask an overall well known concept on SO